# SQLite changes() counts non-changing UPDATEs

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have question regarding SQLite's `changes()` function, which, according to the [documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#changes), "*returns the number of database rows that were changed or inserted or deleted by the most recently completed INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statement*" (also see the [documentation of the underlying C/C++ function](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html)).

I was hoping to use this function to check whether the execution of an `UPDATE` statement pertaining to a single row has *really* caused that row to be changed or not.
By *changed* I do not just mean that the row matched the statement's `WHERE` clause. No, instead what I mean is that, for the row in question, the value of at least 1 column is actually *different* after the execution compared to before. If you ask me this is the only proper definition of a *change* in this context.

So I was hoping to detect such *changes* by checking whether `changes()` returns `1` (row changed) or `0` (row unchanged) when called right after the execution of the `UPDATE` statement.
But much to my despair this does not seem to work as expected.

Allow me to illustrate:

```
CREATE TABLE People (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO People (Name) VALUES ("Astrid");
SELECT changes();
```

Here `changes()` returns `1`, as expected because we just `INSERT`ed 1 row.

```
UPDATE People SET Name = "Emma" WHERE Id = 1;
SELECT changes();
```

Here `changes()` returns `1`, as expected because 1 row was `UPDATE`d (i.e. actually *changed*: the `Name` of the `Person` with `Id = 1` was `"Astrid"` but is now `"Emma"`).

```
UPDATE People SET Name = "John" WHERE Id = 200;
SELECT changes();
```

Here `changes()` returns `0`, as expected because there is no row with `Id = 200`.

So far so good. But now have a look at the following `UPDATE` statement, which *does* indeed match an existing row, but *does not* actually *change* it at all (`Name` remains set to `"Emma"`)...

```
UPDATE People SET Name = "Emma" WHERE Id = 1;
SELECT changes();
```

Here `changes()` returns `1`, while I was of course hoping for `0` :-(.

Perhaps this would have made sense if the function was called something like `matched_rows()` or `affected_rows()`. But for a function called `changes()`, and documented as it is, this behaviour strikes me as illogical, or confusing at best.

So anyway, can somebody explain why this happens, or, even better, suggest an alternative strategy to achieve my goal in a reliable (and efficient) way?

All I can think of is to actually do something like `SELECT * FROM People WHERE Id = x`, compare all returned column values with the values I'm about to set in the `UPDATE` statement and thereby decide whether I need to execute the `UPDATE` at all. But that can't be very efficient, right?
Of course in this toy example it might not matter much, but in my actual application I'm dealing with tables with many more columns, some of which are (potentially big) `BLOB`s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The database does not compare old and new values; any UPDATEd row always counts as "changed" even if the values happen to be the same.
The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) says that

> the UPDATE affects … those rows for which the result of evaluating the WHERE clause expression as a boolean expression is true.

If you want to check the old value, you have to do it explicitly:

```
UPDATE People SET Name = 'Emma' WHERE Id = 1 AND Name IS NOT 'Emma';
```